# kotlin lambda expressions as optional parameter

Tags: android, lambda, expression, kotlin

How can I pass **lambda expression** as optional parameter in **Kotlin** language

```
val max = { a: Int, b: Int ->
  if (a > b)
      a
  else
      b
}
```

I have to pass above thing is like optional parameter

Comment: What do you want to pass this lambda to?

Comment: Side note, there already is a `max` function available in the JDK, accessible via `Math.max(a, b)` which does the same thing.

Comment: Regarding your question though, I don't really understand what you're asking - you can pass `max` as a normal argument to any function call that takes a function of the form `(Int, Int) -> Int`.

Comment: Here I given MAX as example because i can't share my code , and it should work for all type of lambda expressions

Answer (score 17):

You can use your `max` function as default

```
fun someDefault(f: (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int = max) {
    f(1, 7)
    // do something
}
```

or you can also define a method with lambda as parameter which is optional

```
fun someOptional(f: ((a: Int, b: Int) -> Int)? = null) {
    f?.invoke(1, 7)
}
```

In both cases (default and optional) you can specify a lambda for the call or you can just omit it

```
fun call() {
    someDefault()
    someDefault { a, b -> a * b}

    someOptional()
    someOptional { a, b -> a * b}
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The following defines a function that *accepts a function*, and specifies a default value for the passed function if none is supplied.

```
fun foobar(fn: (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int = { a: Int, b: Int -> if (a > b) a else b }) {
  println(fn(42, 99))
}
```

You can pass your own functions:

```
val min = { a: Int, b: Int -> if (a <= b) a else b }
foobar(min)

val max = { a: Int, b: Int -> if (a > b) a else b }
foobar(max)
```

You can omit the function and use the default:

```
foobar()
```

Alternatively you could refer to the standard library `maxOf` function as the default, rather than write your own:

```
fun foobar(fn: (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int = ::maxOf) {
  println(fn(42, 99))
}
```